# how to remove error : X is not a class template

Tags: templates, c++11

I'm no expert in using templates but I'm not sure why I'm getting `error: 'SLinked_List' is not a class template: friend class SLinked_List<T>;` in the definition of class `SNode`. What is wrong with this piece of code?

Thank you,
Pranav

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class SNode{
    friend class SLinked_List<T>;
private:
    T data;
    SNode<T>* next;
};

template <typename T>
class SLinked_List{

private:
    SNode<T>* head;

public:
    SLinked_List(){
        head = nullptr;
    }

    bool empty() const { return head == nullptr; }

    void insert_first (const T&);

};

template <typename T>
void SLinked_List<T> :: insert_first (const T& t){
    SNode<T>* node = new SNode<T>;
    node->data = t;
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}

int main(){

    SLinked_List<std::string> ls;

    ls.insert_first("Hello");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use template arguments to refer to a name you are saying that this type already exists as a template and I want to reference a specific specialization of that template. Inside `SNode`, `SLinked_List` hasn't been declared yet, so this can't be allowed because the compiler doesn't even know if it's a template yet.

It's clear you want to befriend the specialization taking a `T`, so you need to declare `SLinked_List` before `SNode`:

```
template <typename T>
class SLinked_List;

template <typename T>
class SNode{
    friend class SLinked_List<T>;
private:
    T data;
    SNode<T>* next;
};
```

Now the compiler knows that `SLinked_List` is a template and can be referenced as such.

Comment: oh, that I didn't know! Thank @0x499602D2 for the inputs. :)